# PHP preg_match car license plate

Tags: php, preg-match

So I just learned about preg_match in PHP the other day and now i'm trying to preg_match a license plate. It should check for this:

`9a-4e-yy`, so a `-` and before and after that numbers or letters and then a `-` again and more numbers or letters. But it has to be exactly 2 numbers or letters next to each other, not more.

For now I have this code:

```
return preg_match("/^([0-9])"."([0-9])"."(\-([0-9])"."([0-9]))"."(\-([0-9])"."([0-9]))$/", $kenteken );
```

But that only checks on numbers.

I hope you guys could help me to get it work with letters too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What county are you coding for that the license plate letters are possibly lowercase?

Comment: @mickmackusa This question is 5 years old :) The IRL license plate isn't in uppercase, but it's just more user friendly that way because users don't have to worry about uppercase and we can uppercase it later. It's for a Dutch license plate btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[0-9]` matches only numbers.  If you want to match numbers or letters then you need `[0-9A-Za-z]`.

A full regex to do what you want is `^[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}){2}$`

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9a-z]{2}-[0-9a-z]{2}-[0-9a-z]{2}$/i', $kenteken);
```

`[0-9a-z]` means any digit "0" through "9" or any (lower-case) letter "a" through "z". `{2}` means match exactly 2 characters. The `/i` at the end means case-insensitive matching, so it will match upper case letters as well.

Comment: This answer is more efficient that cdhowie's in terms of steps because it does not use a capture group.  The case-insensitive pattern modifier is a logical improvement as well.  To decrease pattern length, `\d` can be used in place of `0-9`.  Unless told other wise, I don't think any license plates in the world use lowercase, so `/^[\dA-Z]{2}-[\dA-Z]{2}-[\dA-Z]{2}$/` would do nicely.