# PHP - preg_match for car license plate number(and letters)

Tags: php

I seen this post in other question([PHP preg_match car license plate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185695/php-preg-match-car-license-plate)) about how to validate if a user actually writes something in the form field to validate if it's actually right. I mean for ex. in my case I need what my real car license plate number to be *AAA-111* , 3 character, dash and 3 numbers. 
This is what I founded in StackOverflow to match *9a-4e-yy* `return preg_match[0-9A-Za-z]{2}(-[0-9A-Za-z]{2}){2}$` , but I need *AAA-111* and it should return in function so I can use it in other classes. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{3}/`. This is case insensitive.

You could also upper case the string and run it thru `/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{3}/`.

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{3}/';
$subject = 'aaa-111';
$result = preg_match( $pattern, $subject , $matches );
echo $result;
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: what about `'/.../i'` ? I prefer to use case ignore flag.

Comment: `/[a-z]{3}-[0-9]{3}/i` also works. I don't know what is faster though, the flag OR the extra pattern.